# Unit testing authenticated Flask blueprint endpoint

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I am creating unit tests for my Flask blueprint endpoints. All is fine until I add the authentication decorator from the flask_azure_oauth library. I tried different approaches, like to mock the FlaskAzureOauth object, but with no success. Could someone help me out find a working solution? Below is a simplified code to reproduce the issue. I'm using pytest for running the unit tests.

**flask_oauth.py**

```
from flask import current_app
from flask_azure_oauth import FlaskAzureOauth

auth = FlaskAzureOauth()
auth.init_app(current_app)
```

**todolist_dummy.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, Response
from api.helpers.flask_oauth import auth

todolist_dummy = Blueprint('todolist_dummy', __name__)


@todolist_dummy.route('/api/todolist', methods=['GET'])
@auth('role')
def get_todolist():
    results_1 = json.dumps([{'id': 'test', 'owner': '1234', 'description': 'description'}])
    return Response(results_1, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
```

**main.py**

```
from flask_cors import CORS


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    with app.app_context():
        app.config['DEBUG'] = True
        app.config['AZURE_OAUTH_TENANCY'] = '8e96d208-e318-485c-9ca6-2409a80b4c8d'
        app.config['AZURE_OAUTH_APPLICATION_ID'] = '2d5f9b24-4e92-43cf-880f-2cbd3ecb0470'
        CORS(app)
        from api.routes.todolist.todolist_dummy import todolist_dummy
        app.register_blueprint(todolist_dummy)

    @app.route("/")
    def hello_world():
        return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"

    return app
```

**todolist_test.py**

```
import pytest
from flask_azure_oauth import FlaskAzureOauth
from unittest.mock import patch


@pytest.fixture()
def app():
    with patch.object(FlaskAzureOauth, "init_app"):
        app = create_app('test')
        yield app


@pytest.fixture()
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()


@pytest.fixture()
def runner(app):
    return app.test_cli_runner()


def test_get_todolist(client):
    response = client.get("/api/todolist")
    assert 'description' in response.json[0]
```

The code is working fine, it does proper authorization based on the bearer token. It is just the unit test I need to fix.